# Finding the zero of a derivative

Tags: statistics, summation, normal-distribution

I have a question on finding the zero of a function $h(a)$ which:

$$2aE(\bar{X}^2) - 2*\mu*E(\bar{X}),$$
where $\bar{X}$ follows a normal distribution $\left(\mu, \dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$

My work so far:

$$2aE(\bar{X}^2) = 2\mu E(\bar{X})$$
$$\to \dfrac{a}{\mu} = \dfrac{E(\bar{X})}{E(\bar{X}^2)}.$$

I dont know what go from here.

Comment: It's just $a=\frac{\mu E\left(\overline X\right)}{E\left({\overline X}^2\right)}$

Comment: Isn't $E[\overline X]=\mu$?

Comment: I guess. And $E\left({\overline X}^2\right)$ is something else in terms of $\sigma$, $n$ and $\mu$.

Comment: @Gae.S.  Sure.  $E[\overline X^2]=\frac {\sigma^2
}n+\mu^2$.

Comment: I cant really simplify from here right?