# Is $E(X^2) = \mu^2$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am wondering if I have a normal distribution say,

$X \sim {\cal N}(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$

So I know that $E(X) = \mu$

Would $E(X^2) = \mu^2$?

Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. In fact $\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \mu^2 + \sigma^2$ for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: This presumably stems from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3476732/finding-the-zero-of-a-derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong.

Note that $\text{Var}(X)=EX^2-(EX)^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. Therefore, $$EX^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\mu^2$$

We have that
$$EX^2=\int x^2\text{dF}_X(x).$$

In general, this is different of $$\left(\int x\text{dF}_X(x) \right)^2=(EX)^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Sadly it is not that simple.

Take a normal 6 sided dice
$$E[X]=1\frac16+2\frac16+3\frac16+4\frac16+5\frac16+6\frac16=\frac{21}{6}=3.5$$
$$E[X^2]=1^2\frac16+2^2\frac16+3^2\frac16+4^2\frac16+5^2\frac16+6^2\frac16=\frac{92}{6}=15.333\ldots$$